# How to replace values in a STFDF spacetime object in R

Tags: r, subset

I am iteratively filling an STFDF object from the spacetime package on a time step basis, and I am having trouble replacing values in the object. Here is an example of what I would like to do:

```
library(spacetime)
data(air)

# Replace the spatial data from the first time step with that of the 100th
rural[,1] <- rural[,100]
```

The last line produces the error:

```
 object of type 'S4' is not subsettable
```

How should I be subsetting the STFDF? Alternatively, should I make all replacements in a matrix then turn the matrix into a STFDF?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subsetting works, but it is subset-replace you're trying to do, which is not implemented for ST* objects. The easiest is to work with low-level structures (`data.frame` or `matrix`), and when that is complete, build a STFDF, either using the constructor function `STFDF()` or `stConstruct`.

You can replace complete columns, as in

```
rural$PM10 = 10 * rural$PM10
```

but you have to know what you replace it with (which is in particular for `STFDF` not so hard: space cycles fastest)